# Nginx 502 when running Rails (Puma) with -d (daemon)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, daemon, production-environment, puma

Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.2.2.1

I'm trying to make nginx get upstream through puma socket.

When I run `rails s -e production` all is good.

When I run `rails s -e production -d` Nginx returns `502 Bad Gateway`

**config/puma.rb**

```
...
      app_dir = "/home/user/myapp"
      tmp_dir = "#{app_dir}/tmp"
      # Set up socket location
      bind "unix://#{tmp_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"
      # Logging
      stdout_redirect "#{app_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{app_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true
...
```

**etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com**

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/user/myapp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    root /home/user/myapp/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

**var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
    2019/07/07 13:45:09 [error] 21609#21609: *11391 connect() to 
unix:/home/user/myapp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection 
refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.68.11.91, server: 
mydomain.com, request: "GET /pages/one HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://unix:/home/user/myapp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/pages/one", host: "mydomain.com"
```

(P.S. change from original domain to mydomain.com)
What difference? How to fix it? Please explain and help

**UPDATE**

Seems to be running with daemon flag it doesn't create `puma.sock` in /home/user/myapp/tmp/sockets. Why and where is it?

Answer (score 1):

The [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56921395/10871073) does not work any more. The deamon option `-d` is deprecated.

You could use a systemd service:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/puma.service
```

Copy this to the file and fill in your YOUR_APP_PATH and FULLPATH:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

# Uncomment for socket activation (see below)
# Requires=puma.socket

[Service]
# Puma supports systemd's `Type=notify` and watchdog service
# monitoring, if the [sd_notify](https://github.com/agis/ruby-sdnotify) gem is installed,
# as of Puma 5.1 or later.
# On earlier versions of Puma or JRuby, change this to `Type=simple` and remove
# the `WatchdogSec` line.
Type=notify

# If your Puma process locks up, systemd's watchdog will restart it within seconds.
WatchdogSec=10

# Preferably configure a non-privileged user
# User=

# The path to your application code root directory.
# Also replace the "<YOUR_APP_PATH>" placeholders below with this path.
# Example /home/username/myapp
WorkingDirectory=<YOUR_APP_PATH>

# Helpful for debugging socket activation, etc.
# Environment=PUMA_DEBUG=1

# SystemD will not run puma even if it is in your path. You must specify
# an absolute URL to puma. For example /usr/local/bin/puma
# Alternatively, create a binstub with `bundle binstubs puma --path ./sbin` in the WorkingDirectory
ExecStart=/<FULLPATH>/bin/puma -C <YOUR_APP_PATH>/puma.rb

# Variant: Rails start.
# ExecStart=/<FULLPATH>/bin/puma -C <YOUR_APP_PATH>/config/puma.rb ../config.ru

# Variant: Use `bundle exec --keep-file-descriptors puma` instead of binstub
# Variant: Specify directives inline.
# ExecStart=/<FULLPATH>/puma -b tcp://0.0.0.0:9292 -b ssl://0.0.0.0:9293?key=key.pem&cert=cert.pem


Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Run `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload your services.

Then you can use `sudo systemctl restart puma` to restart/start/stop the service

Refer to the  [puma docs](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Dont know why, but It works if run puma (not rails server)

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -d
```